# Fail to link Pylon(Basler) SDK with Qt on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmake

I am trying to link Qt with the Pylon camera SDK in a Qt Creator project.

I install the pylon Camera Software Suite app from this [pylon for OS X](http://www.baslerweb.com/en/support/downloads/software-downloads?type=30&series=0&model=0) and the pylon framework is install at `/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework`.

I first follow the `pylon Programmer's Guide` which is installed with the app to link the pylon with Xcode. It works perfectly.

Then I try to link with my Qt Project. I add this in the `.pro` file:

```
mac: LIBS += -F/Library/Frameworks/ -framework pylon

# add GenICam because pylon Programmer's Guide do so
INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/GenICam
DEPENDPATH += /Library/Frameworks
```

But this doesn't work. Qt cannot find the header files.

I also try:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks/
LIBS += -framework pylon
```

as said in the document [Using Frameworks](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html). But still not working. Anyone help me to fix this? Thanks.

**Update:**

Weird is that Qt can detect auto-complete of the header files but when build it says no such file found.
[image]

Comment: If it answers your question then please choose the correct answer by clicking on checkmark next to the vote

Answer (score 1):

I just answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693847/fail-to-link-pylon-framework-in-qt-creator-on-mac/39694060#39694060):

> *A)* If you are compiling this Pylon framework with source then   In these cases you need source code installation, you need to go to your
>   Pylon source directory, e.g.:
>
> ```
>  <path-to-pylon>/src/include/
> ```
>
> You can locate the directory where PylonIncludes.h is installed by
>   runing the following command:
>
> ```
>   find <path-to-Pylon> -name PylonIncludes.h
> ```
>
> Once you locate the directory   e.g. lets say
>   /Users/kevin/Pylon5.5 then you include add the following line in your
>   CMAkeLists.txt
>
> ```
> INCLUDEPATH += /Users/kevin/Pylon5.5/src/include/
> ```
>
> *B)* If you have binary framework itself then you can workaround by copying all headers to tmporary location under `pylon/<all-headers>`
>
> ```
> cp -rf /Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/* /tmp/pylonHeaders/pylon/ Then use following in .pro file
>
>   INCLUDEPATH += /tmp/pylonHeaders
>   LIBS += -framework pylon
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is an automatism in Xcode when you insert a framework it includes the header directory of the used frameworks automatically.

In your case, simple add this line and the compiler will find the pylon headers.

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
```

I hope this will help you. With best regards

Comment: It may not be a good way, since the pylon API headers all use such form as `#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>`, which means you should not specify the path of header if you want to use the existing API. So you have to link the framework, not only the head files.

Comment: According to Apple documentation. The first entry in an e.g. #include <framework/sample.h> is the framework name. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002257-BAJJBBHJ