# Fail to link pylon framework in Qt creator on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I'm trying to add the pylon framework to Qt creator on Mac.

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks/
LIBS += -framework pylon
```

This doesn't work to me. The error is always `'pylon/PylonIncludes.h' file not found`.

I can specify the header path for Qt creator, e.g. `INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Headers`. But it should be `#include <PylonIncludes.h>`, not `#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>` when including the head file in code.

However, the API headers all use such form as `#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>`, which means I cannot specify the path of header if I want to use the existing API.

Does anyone know how to add pylon framework to Qt creator?

Comment: Why do you expect a linker argument (`LIBS`) to affect include path of the compiler?

Comment: @KubaOber Using Frameworks: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-platform-notes.html#using-frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A)* If you are compiling this Pylon framework with source then

In these cases you need source code installation, you need to go to your Pylon source directory, e.g.:

```
 <path-to-pylon>/src/include/
```

You can locate the directory where PylonIncludes.h is installed by runing the following command:

```
  find <path-to-Pylon> -name PylonIncludes.h
```

Once you locate the directory   e.g. lets say /Users/kevin/Pylon5.5 then you include add the following line in your CMAkeLists.txt

```
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/kevin/Pylon5.5/src/include/
```

*B)* If you have binary framework itself then you can workaround by copying all headers to tmporary location under `pylon/<all-headers>`

```
cp -rf /Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/* /tmp/pylonHeaders/pylon/
```

Then use following in .pro file

```
  INCLUDEPATH += /tmp/pylonHeaders
  LIBS += -framework pylon
```

Comment: What do you mean by going to QT source directory? The pylon framework is installed under `/Library/Frameworks/`.

Comment: Did you compile QT on MAC or used pre-compiled libraries?

Comment: I can't remember that. But I can find the `<path-to-Qt>/src/qtbase/include/`. What should I do next?

Comment: Pylon is a third-party framework, which is not installed with Qt. Why do you include the `qtbase`?

Comment: Awesome! You solved this problem! Actually I added these lines `INCLUDEPATH += /pylonHeaders
INCLUDEPATH += /pylonHeaders/pylon/GenICam
LIBS += -framework pylon` to make it work. BTW, did you ever use pylon with Qt on Mac?  Do the framework (libs, APIs) work well based on this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Please see *Common Settings for Building Applications with pylon* in *Programmer's Guide and API Reference for pylon for OS X* where instructions on how to set up XCode are well described:

This section shows the most common OS X build settings for building an application using pylon and Apple Xcode. Consult the Advanced Topics section for more information, e.g. when a different configuration is required.

First add the pylon framework to your project, right-click on your project and choose **Add files to "< Projectname >"...**. Browse to the install location of the pylon framework, typically **/Library/Frameworks** and choose **pylon.framework**, click **Add** button.

Add the following user-defined variable for Release and Debug configurations to your build target (**Build Settings -> User-Defined -> PYLON_LIBRARY_DIR**):

```
/Library
```

Add the following Framework Search Paths for Release and Debug configurations to your build target (**Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Framework Search Paths**):

```
$(PYLON_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
```

Add the following Header Search Paths for Release and Debug configurations to your build target (**Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths**):

```
$(PYLON_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/GenICam
```

Add the following Runpath Search Path for Release and Debug configurations to your build target (**Build Settings -> Linking -> Runpath Search Path**):

```
$(PYLON_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks
```

Comment: Please format your answer, the parts that are codes should look different, use quick help when your push edit