# How to link pylon camera to qt creater on linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, camera

I am trying to connect a Basler camera to my qt application on linux but I am not able to include any of the pylon header files because I don't know what extra things to add my .pro file other than "QT  += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets". If any one of you can help me on this then I'll be grateful to you guys.

Comment: What research have you done? This is almost certainly referred to in the many tutorials out there. Show what research you've done, and maybe share the relevant file details so people don't have to redo your work.

Comment: I tried to find something on how to connect pylon camera to qt on linux but I didn't find anything that's why I posted a question here. I don't even know how to proceed on this. Can you please help me on this and provide relevant links please.

Comment: Unfortunately, [SO] is not a great tutorial site, and this question seems to be about how to do some specific thing with a specific API under specific circumstances. At the end of the day this is just a library and API being used with C++. Some of the info out there will probably apply or at least give you a hint. You are encouraged to continue with your research until someone finds this question interesting enough to form and answer.

Comment: Given that a Mac is pretty close to *NIX often, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39421854/1531971 Also, just search "pylon qt c++" on the web.